# Some Payment Method Not Showing in Sales grid after upgrade magento to 2.3.1

Tags: sales-order, payment-methods, magento2.3, order-grid, magento2.3.1

I upgraded Magento version 2.2.3 to 2.3.1 by using composer. All Things are working fine, except Sales order grid. In sales grid it's showing only payment method check, rest other payment methods are not showing in grid.

[image]

But they are visible in details.
[image]

I have checked below file 
vendor/magento/module-payment/Helper/Data.php 
in this file function **getPaymentMethodList** have a validation for active method.

My all methods are active and showing in frontside but not showing in grid.

I have disabled all 3rd party modules also but no luck.

Comment: even in new orders with 60 Day Payment Terms - payment method? still not showing?

Comment: @magefms, No it's not showing.

We renamed COD with 60 Day Payment Terms - payment method in admin side

Comment: is 60 day payment terms a custom extension?

Comment: @magefms, We renamed COD with 60 Day Payment Terms - payment method in admin side –

Comment: check if there might be another custom module that overrides sales_order_grid ui component

Comment: @magefms, This is Magento core issue.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22231

Comment: You should have gone for 2.3.2 :)

Answer (score 0):

This is Magento issue please check [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22231)  link for same

Comment: Already mentioned in the comment, Issue created by me on Github https://prnt.sc/oig0t6